# Как избавится от дублирования записей в таблице БД при UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

На странице есть несколько полей формы с одинаковым именем name='protectMean[]'.
UPDATE срабатывает только если в самом последнем поле формы я меняю значение. и то ..в таком случае новое значение дублируется во всех полях таблицы БД где personSurname = $order_surname

Помогите пожалуйста.мне нужно чтобы значения в таблице БД обновлялись относительно измененных значений в форме.

Нужно использовать distinct? если да, то каким образом

```
$n=sizeof($_POST['protectMean']);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
    $qty=$_POST['protectMean'][$i];
    $update= $GLOBALS['pdo']->prepare
    ("UPDATE protect_means SET nameOfMeans = :value1 WHERE personSurname = :order_surname");
    $update->bindParam(':value1', $qty);
    $update->bindParam(':order_surname', $order_surname);
    $update->execute();
}
```

Comment: Прикрепи структуру таблицы к вопросу

Comment: $order_surname - это шта? Если в нём весь цикл статичное значение, то логично, что он записывает последнее значение из $_POST['protectMean']. Он тупо перезаписывает одно и тоже поле в базе столько раз, сколько там в скрипте for-ов.

Comment: @Евгений, [ссылка](https://prnt.sc/qeopgs)

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите. У вас проблема в том, что после изменения поля изменяется все значения полей где `personSurname = $order_surname`? Тогда сделайте так чтоб `personSurname` было уникальное. Или вы хотите чтоб при любом изменение формы, у вас изменялось лишь то поле которое изменилось?

Comment: @Евгений, как раз и нужно чтобы перезаписывались все поля в таблице, где personSurname = $order_surname. точнее те поля которые были изменены в форме пользователем.

Comment: @Евгений, Извините, возможно я ужасно объясняю((( ....
Постараюсь описать на скринах. [ссылка](https://prnt.sc/qeszkn) - 
Это изначальная структура. т.е пользователь с фамилией ivanov ввел в форму
 "головной убор" и "очки зашитные", нажал сохранить. Затем он решает изменить название 
"головной убор" на "шапка" и снова жмет сохранить - [ссылка](https://prnt.sc/qet03j) . И после этого
 в таблице происходит такая история - [ссылка](https://prnt.sc/qet09l)
 А мне нужно чтобы было так - с[ссылка](https://prnt.sc/qetdo5)

Comment: @АняАлиновская для этого надо получить старое значение обновляемой записи, чтоб запрос примерно выглядел как `WHERE personSurname = :order_surname AND nameOfMeans = :old_value` или в форме установить `protectMean[$item_id]`, где $item_id - id обновляемой записи, и разобрать массив через `foreach($key=>$value)`, где `$key ` и будет $item_id

Comment: @Guest , Спасибо! Работает